# Pass multiple arguments to $.delegate

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, delegates

the arguments come from jQuery as `$(this)` and contain multiple elements :)

tried

```
  $('#el').delegate($(this), 'click' ...

  $('#el').delegate($(this).each(), 'click' ...
```

none work..

---

```
(function($){
  $.fn.myfunction= function(){

    // here i need to somehow find .a, .b., .c etc... 
    $('#el').delegate($(this), 'click', function(event){

    });

  });
});
```

later I'm calling it like:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      $('.a, .b, .c').myfunction();
  });
```

so I want my event on all new .a, .b, .c ...

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to hook a function on the click event of certain elements

Comment: That still doesn't make any sense. What is `this` in this context? Maybe you should show a little HTML and/or the code around your code above.

Comment: I posted more code, sorry I dont know how to explain this better :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your code, you will need `$("xxxx").bind('click',function(e) {...});` OR `$("xxx").live('click', function(e) {...});`.

If you are on jquery v1.7, [$.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is the function to use and $.off() reverses it.

Answer (score 2):

You should add a normal handler:

```
$(this).bind('click', ...);
```

You can also just write `$(this).click(...)`

`.delegate` allows you to handle all events that occur in children of an element that match a selector.